# Chromatic number of a simple graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a simple graph such that $$\chi(G-x-y)=\chi(G)-2,$$ for any distinct vertices $x$ and $y$, then $G$ is a complete graph.

> I know that if $G$ is a simple graph we have that $\chi(G)\leq n$, where $n$ is the number vertices of $G$. Moreover, if we consider two distinct vertices of $G$, we have that $\chi(G-x-y)\leq n-2$. Therefore, $\chi(G-x-y)\leq 2n-2-\chi(G)$. For me it's clear that equality is true for a complete graph, because if $G$ is a complete graph we have $\chi(G) = n$ and consequently $\chi(G-x-y)=n-2=\chi(G)-2$.

**I'm not sure if this thinking is correct, can anyone help me to justify that $G$ is a complete graph?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $G$ is not complete. Then there are vertices $x,y$ not joined by an edge.
Consider a colouring of $G-x-y$ with $m=\chi(G-x-y)$ colours. Then by assigning a new $(m+1)$st colour to $x$ and $y$, we obtain a valid colouring of $G$ and conclude that
$$ \chi(G)\le \chi(G-x-y)+1.$$